# Stripe Element Quickstart example not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, stripe-payments

I am just getting started with [Stripe's Element Quickstart](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart). I have [the following fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5w69egk7/). As you can see, it looks nothing like the example. I've even loaded their https://js.stripe.com/v3/ file but have no idea what I'm missing:

```
<form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="card-element">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>
    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  </div>

  <button>Submit Payment</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It looks like they have other styles for the label, form, and button declared farther up that give it the extra css to make it look like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page that the example is on [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart) defines styles for the form, button, label, etc. You can find this css if you open up the console on their example site and search for this style tag `<style media="screen">` embedded in the html. Add the css to your fiddle and it will look like their example.

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f7f8f9;
  color: #6b7c93;
}

*, label {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-variant: normal;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #32325d;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, .11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
  transition: all 150ms ease;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-top: 28px;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(50, 50, 93, .10), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  background-color: #43458b;
}

form {
  padding: 30px;
  height: 120px;
}

label {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#card-errors {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  color: #fa755a;
}

.form-row {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}

.token {
  color: #32325d;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 670px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#stripe-token-handler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 100px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.1),
    0 15px 35px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.15),
    0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: white;
}

#stripe-token-handler.is-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-80px);
}

/**
 * The CSS shown here will not be introduced in the Quickstart guide, but shows
 * how you can use CSS to style your Element's container.
 */
.StripeElement {
  background-color: white;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
  transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
}

.StripeElement--focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.StripeElement--invalid {
  border-color: #fa755a;
}

.StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}
```